# Is there a way to obtain the email image using an API?

Tags: c#, image, gmail

[image]

I tried all the Google APIs, I can't find a single one.

When I enter an email to send a message, Gmail gets the email with the user and the photo.

I am developing a web application and I would like to implement the method of obtaining the name and photo, more than anything the photo.

Comment: Both the email and webpage are html.  So it is possible.  Best way is to save the email to a file and then look at the html in Notepad (or other text editor).  You should be able to send the same html in the body of a request to your webpage.